# CEF4Delphi Application font size decreased after CEF is loaded

Tags: delphi, cef4delphi

I have a very strange behavior. After CEF libraries are loaded, all the fonts in WHOLE application are decreased. It happened after I have migrated to the newest version of CEF (117.2.5) from version 96.

It is a Windows 32 bit application written and compiled with Delphi 2007.
The application is complex, it has a lot of dynamically loaded libraries (BPLs).

The strangest thing is that this happens only on some machines (Win10 Enterprise N and Win10 Professional 64 bit). None of them has Delphi IDE installed, so I can't debug it.

The CEF is loaded with code, run with subprocesses:

```
  sciezkaRoot := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(GetRootPath());
  sciezkaBinariow := sciezkaRoot + CHROMIUM_FOLDER_BINARIOW;
  sciezkaProcesu := sciezkaRoot + CHROMIUM_FOLDER_KOMUNIKACJA_MARKETINGOWA + CHROMIUM_PROCES_EXE;
  try
    if not FileExists(sciezkaProcesu) then
      raise Exception.Create('Brak wymaganego pliku w lokalizacji:' + #13 + sciezkaProcesu);
    uCEFApplication.GlobalCEFApp := TCefApplication.Create();
    with uCEFApplication.GlobalCEFApp do
    begin
      ShowMessageDlg := False;
      MissingBinariesException := True;
      BackgroundColor := ColorToTCefColor(clBtnFace);
      Cache := fKatalogCache;
      EnablePrintPreview := False;
      EnableGPU := False;
      FrameworkDirPath := sciezkaBinariow;
      ResourcesDirPath := sciezkaBinariow;
      LocalesDirPath := sciezkaBinariow + 'locales';
      LocalesRequired := 'pl';
      Locale := 'pl';
      SetCurrentDir := True;
      BrowserSubprocessPath := sciezkaProcesu;
      Result := StartMainProcess();
    end;
  except
    on e: Exception do
    begin
      FreeAndNil(uCEFApplication.GlobalCEFApp);
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;
```

It does not matter if I load any web page or not.

Any ideas what is happening and why?

Comment: Have you tried asking this on the CEF4Delphi site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CEF had some issues about this in recent versions because Chromium sets the Windows process DPI awareness if unset.

- Either add a [manifest with some value for the DPI awareness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process#setting-default-awareness-with-the-application-manifest)...:

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <asmv3:application>
      <asmv3:windowsSettings>
        <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">false</dpiAware>
        <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">unaware</dpiAwareness>
      </asmv3:windowsSettings>
    </asmv3:application>
  </assembly>
  ```
- ...or call [`SetProcessDpiAwareness()` with the value `PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE` (that is `0`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-setprocessdpiawareness) before loading the CEF.

Read these issues for more information:

- [Windows: Remove CefEnableHighDPISupport function which is no longer needed #3452](https://github.com/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/3452)
- [Dpi crash on launch #484](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi/issues/484)
- [about scale #489](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi/issues/489)

Comment: Thank you very much.
Seems adding a manifest solved the problem.